# Precise Printer Interface- no options

Tags: printing

I am trying to troubleshoot an HP printer in Precise with Gnome Fallback. When I click on "printers", I get a box that shows the printer it auto detected, which is correct, but it hsn NO options to view/change the driver, add a printer, or anything else that was available in Lucid.

Answer (score 0):

If you enter `localhost:631` (just that and nothing else) in your browser you should come to the `CUPS` interface, from which you can manage your printer. The tabs labelled `administration` and `printers` should allow you to do most things such as checking the status of a printer, or even adding a printer if it isn't there. Within the `printers` tab, you can click on a printer there and it will give you a lot of maintenance and other administration options.

Comment: Great tip on localhost:631! But for all the command line options it has, I do not see one for switching drivers. It only tells me which driver it is using. I have a major color issue (teal flesh tones etc), yet it prints perfectly if I boot into Lucid instesd of Precise. Prior versions of Ubuntu gave me a dropdown list of drivers to chose from. Part of the problem might be that HPLIP is showing a "device communication error".

Comment: Have you tried changing the colour profile for the printer? Also, you can get a list of drivers if you go to cups, printers, click on your printer, administration, modify printer. Then enter your username and password and on the third screen or so you should be presented with a drop down list.